# Chrome adds grey seperators between divs when firefox doesn't

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I couldn't find an answer to this yet.

I have this list made with divs.
All the divs have border and outline set to 0.

Now, when I look at it in Firefox, it looks just how I want it to look:
Grey and White switching without any borders.

[image: Firefox]

But when I use Chrome to look at the same thing, it just adds these grey borders that don't fit in my design.

[image: Chrome]

I really have no idea why Chrome does this.
I hope any of you guys can help me.

Thanks,
David

I already added a normalize.css file but this didn't help.

This is the page:
https://gmod-lsm.com/l/demo.php?u=5c3fa6c18685f&steamid=%s

I am talking about the div class="rules-info" and the div class="rules-item", that make up the list.

I really don't know where those gray borders come from. Not from my css as far as I can tell. They have to do with Chrome.

Comment: You can add `.rules-item {
    margin-top: -1px;}` but honestly I don't know why there is a distance. David 3 ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have a lot of heights and paddings with decimal values. In retina screens, for example, you will see gaps between those decimals. Remember you're not supposed to divide pixels.

I made an experiment, giving the parent container a background color of red, and as expected, the gaps turned red:

[image]

Maybe firefox is rounding out some of those values but, why have them in the first place?

I suppose you have some sort of automatic website builder doing this odd calculation?

Comment: Thank you! This actually fixed the issue. Although on smaller screen resolutions (@media screen and (max-width: 1152px), screen and (max-height: 745px)) with all the decimals removed this still occurs. I just set the .rules-info's background to white which fixes that aswell (Thanks David 2 :))

Comment: It's not only widths and heights, you also have paddings with decimals. Those decimals will always result in those minute variable glitches.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add `background:#fff` rather than `transparent`, which appears to solve your issue.

```
.rules-info {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 362.19px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It's a workaround, not really a solution. To avoid confusion about our names: call me David 3, full of Davids here ;-)

Comment: Although the problem was that the pixels have decimals in them, this answer still helped me because Sotkra's strangely didn't work everywhere. I just added the white background and the grey lines vanished. Thank you